# Se debe seguir el principio DRY (don't repeat yourself) en respuestas y que significa eso para enlaces?

Tags: discusión, respuesta

En una conversación por comentarios surgió el tema de que si es aceptable/cortés/productivo de responder a preguntas con enlaces, en este caso con un enlace a Wikipedia.

Es valido y/o buena practica de responder en forma más directo y corto al problema concreto y agregar enlaces para la base teórica del asunto?

Que opinan?

Para referencia, la pregunta en que surgió la conversación se encuentra [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/43645/dominios-hechos-con-ip/43662#43662).

Comment: Basado en tu comentario: "No creo que es necesario de copiar y pegar informaciónes de otros lugares aquí si ya existen en otra parte". Mi comentario intenta decir que [**la respuesta no puede ser solo un enlace o grupo de enlaces**](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/959/227) (revisar el punto #12). Yo te diría que a veces es necesario citar de manera textual y posiblemente agregar una explicación sobre la cita. Hay varios ejemplos de esto, sobretodo cuando se solicita comprender parte de especificaciones de lenguajes de programación o asociado a temas de licencias de software, entre otros.

Answer (score 5):

Yo opino que la respuesta debe contener toda la información necesaria para contestar a la pregunta sin necesidad de consultar sitios externos.

Los enlaces externos deben ampliar la respuesta, pero no deben ser un requisito para que dicha respuesta sea comprendida y/o aceptada. **Un enlace no puede ser una respuestas**.

En mi opinión, un uso correcto de los enlaces debe ser para citar fuentes de información, por ejemplo.

Comment: Coincido con lo que comentas. Un enlace es una herramienta pero por si solo no suele ser una respuesta, sino una recomendación (y por ende un comentario)

Comment: Un enlace sí es una respuesta. No será la respuesta que te gusta. No será una respuesta válida en SO. No es seguro que el sito enlazado siga existiendo dentro de X tiempo. Y habrá otras cosas que no sea. Pero indiscutiblemente sí es una respuesta.

Comment: Nunca fue que el enlace sea la respuesta, creo que en eso deberíamos ser todos de acuerdo. Para puro enlaces hay google, yahoo, ask... etc. 
Concuerdo también que la respuesta dado debería ser autosuficiente para el caso particular, y si no es posible de dar una respuesta valida en el contexto sin un montón de enlaces externos, probablemente la pregunta no fue para SO. Buen punto con que un enlace externo podría ya no existir en un futuro lejano, entonces sería bueno de tener criterio en que enlaces se usan. En resumen aun sigo pensando que lo más productivo es quedarse con DRY.

Answer (score -1):

Yo opino que sería útil de tratar de aplicar el principio DRY en las respuestas, respondiendo al problema concreta con propios palabras mientras tanto dando enlaces que dan acceso a más base teórica. Obviamente es completamente valido de escribir una explicación propia de la base teórica también, pero en la mayoría de los casos no me parece ni productivo ni necesario.

Explico mis razones:

Enlaces ayudan de separar la ayuda concreta con el problema en particular mientras tanto dando acceso fácil a más información si eso es necesario. Ademas tomando en cuenta la valoración de las maquinas de búsqueda, enlaces a fuentes relevantes aumentan la visibilidad de la contribución en aquellos, fomentando la utilidad de la plataforma aun más.